# Spring Integration ConcurrentMetadataStore / RedisMetadataStore

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-integration

We have an application where we need to poll a folder and process the files. 
We are using clustered environment and on each server files are getting processed using multiple threads. I am using FileInBoundAdapter, poller and Task-executor. But I am seeing the same files are getting processed in different threads. After reading Spring integration documentation it seems ConcurrentMetadataStore/RedisMetadataStore will help to avoid this issue. 
I am trying to find out a sample code for RedisMetadataStore API.
Can someone help me sample code or suggest different solution?

Thanks,
Mohan

Answer (score 0):

The sample is pretty simple. You just need to supply the `RedisConnectionFactory` to the same Redis server for all your cluster nodes and inject `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` to your `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>`s:

```
<bean id="redisMetadataStore" class="org.springframework.integration.redis.metadata.RedisMetadataStore">
   <constructor-arg ref="redisConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="acceptOnceFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
   <constructor-arg ref="redisMetadataStore"/>
   <constructor-arg value="the_key"/>
</bean>

<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter filter="acceptOnceFilter"/>
```

Comment: does this work if we want 2  instances of an application to pick 2 different files at the same time to achieve concurrency